# Why is my Access Database connection vb stating authentication failed

Tags: excel, vba, database, ms-access

[image]

I'm trying to use Microsoft Access for the first time. Using it to create a database for information that I will pull from numerous Microsoft Excel files. Unfortunately as I'm trying to set up functions and connections to the database from the Excel files, I've gotten this error that I'm not sure how to solve. I've been using resources online to try and build this for the first time, but I haven't seen anyone with the specific issue for myself. This error seems to occur each time it passes through one of my functions I have. I hope someone might be able to provide some insight. It seems that each time I run it and go to debug it highlights .Open with the error in my GetKeyID Function. But I've never seen this before.

```
Sub TestTransferDataToAccess()
    Dim ConnObj As ADODB.Connection
    Dim RecSet As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ConnCmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim ColNames As ADODB.Fields
    Dim DataSource As String
    Dim intLoop As Integer
    
    'Datasource
    DataSource = "O:\Department\Engineering\Einstein\00 - Systems Engineering\04 - Databases\VerificationLogDB.accdb"
    
    'Create a new connection object & a new command object
    Set ConnObj = New ADODB.Connection
    Set ConnCmd = New ADODB.Command
    
    'Create a new connection
    With ConnObj
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = DataSource
        .Open
    End With
    
    'command object to use Active Connection shortcut method
    ConnCmd.ActiveConnection = ConnObj
    
    ' Define Excel workbook and worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    ' Set Excel workbook and worksheet
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("O:\Swap\Chicago\GenoF\Reading-2021-03-22-10-14-48.xls")
    ' Set worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("As Found-CW Data")
    
    ' Loop through Excel data and insert into Access database
    Dim headerID As Long
    Dim keyID As Long
    Dim torqueValue As Double
    Dim row As Long
    
    For row = 16 To 25 ' Rows B16 to B25 for Channel 1 data
        headerID = GetHeaderID(ws.Cells(row, 2).Value) ' Used for header lookup
        keyID = GetKeyID("Channel 1") ' Used for key lookup
        torqueValue = CDbl(ws.Cells(row, 3).Value) ' Used for torque data cell
        
        ' Insert data into Access database
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblTorqueData (headerID, keyID, torqueValue) VALUES (" & headerID & ", " & keyID & ", " & torqueValue & ")"
        ConnCmd.Execute strSQL
        
        
    Next row
    
    ' Close the Recordset and Connection
    RecSet.Close
    ConnObj.Close
    Set RecSet = Nothing
    Set ConnCmd = Nothing
    Set ConnObj = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Data transfer to Access completed."
End Sub

Function GetHeaderID(headerName As String) As Long
    'variables for database connection
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim RecSet As ADODB.Recordset
    
    'Define the Datasource
    DataSource = "O:\Department\Engineering\Einstein\00 - Systems Engineering\04 - Databases\VerificationLogDB.accdb"
     
    'Create a new connection object & a new command object
    Set ConnObj = New ADODB.Connection
    Set ConnCmd = New ADODB.Command
    
    'Create a new connection
    With ConnObj
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = DataSource
        .Open
    End With
    
    'Allow command object to use the Active Connection shortcut method
    'ConnCmd.ActiveConnection = ConnObj
    
    ' Use SQL query to retrieve HeaderID based on headerName
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT HeaderID FROM tblHeaders WHERE HeaderName = '" & headerName & "'"
    
     'Execute the Query & Get the Column Names.
    'rs.Open strSQL, conn
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
       ' Check if record was found
    'If Not rs.EOF Then
     '   GetHeaderID = rs.Fields(0).Value
    'Else
        ' Handle the case where no record was found
     '   GetHeaderID = -1 ' Replace with default value
    'End If

    
        ' Close the Connection
    ConnObj.Close
    
    ' Release ADODB objects
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
End Function

Function GetKeyID(keyName As String) As Long
    ' variables for database connection
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim RecSet As ADODB.Recordset
    
    'path to Access database file
    Dim dbPath As String
    dbPath = "O:\Department\Engineering\Einstein\00 - Systems Engineering\04 - Databases\VerificationLogDB.laccdb"
    
    'database and recordset
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
     
     'Create a new connection
    With conn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = DataSource
        .Open
    End With
    
    'Allow command object to use the Active Connection shortcut method
    ConnCmd.ActiveConnection = ConnObj
    
    ' Use SQL query to retrieve KeyID based on keyName
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT KeyID FROM tblKeys WHERE KeyName = '" & keyName & "'"
    
    ' Execute query and get result
    Set RecSet = ConnCmd.Execute
    'rs.Open strSQL, conn
    
    ' Check if record was found
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        GetKeyID = rs.Fields(0).Value
    Else
        ' Handle case where no record was found
        GetKeyID = -1 ' Replace with appropriate default value
    End If
    
    ' Close the Recordset and Connection
    rs.Close
    conn.Close
    
    ' Release ADODB objects
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: What is the entire error?

Comment: I'll add a screenshot of what it looks like

Comment: I've made that necessary change. I did not see that beforehand, 
 thank you. You are right, it wasn't the cause of the error, but it's appreciated! ; )

Comment: I did not think of adding an option explicit, that's interesting. I can try. Currently my Datasource is showing empty in my Locals window.

Comment: The `WHERE HeaderName = '" & headerName  & "'"` part of the code is **REALLY DANGEROUS**, and same for `keyName`. I may disagree with the answer about using a single connection, but the part of example there using query parameters is IMPORTANT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told us the error occurs at the connection `.Open` step in your `GetKeyID` function.  So I suggest you narrow your focus to that specific operation (open an ADODB connection).

Here is sample code which runs without error on my system.  Change the value of `dbPath` back to yours and test it. It will print 1 (for `State`) to the Immediate window if successful.

```
Public Sub test_connection()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim DataSource As String
    Dim dbPath As String
    
    'dbPath = "O:\Department\Engineering\Einstein\00 - Systems Engineering\04 - Databases\VerificationLogDB.laccdb"
    dbPath = "C:\Users\hansu\AppData\Roaming\AccessApps\AppStarter.accdb"
    DataSource = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
     
    With conn
        .ConnectionString = DataSource
        .Open
        Debug.Print .State
    End With
End Sub
```

Notice `Dim DataSource As String` and later the `DataSource =`  line.  Your code did not include either.  That is why you found *["my Datasource is showing empty in my Locals window"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77068339/why-is-my-access-database-connection-vb-stating-authentication-failed/77069613#comment135865104_77068339)*.  Without `Dim DataSource`, Access considers `DataSource` to be an undeclared variant, and since you never assigned it a value, it remains an empty variant.  So naturally connection `Open` fails.

Add `Option Explicit` to your code module's Declarations section.  Then at least Access can alert you to an undeclared variable.

Also it looks like you were attempting to connect to a lock file, `VerificationLogDB.laccdb`.  Connect to a database instead.  My guess is you want to connect to `VerificationLogDB.accdb` (accdb rather than laccdb).

Comment: When adding the code you provided I was also able to get a "1" result. I also saw that what I was calling for the Access had a "l" added in the accdb. I've made the corrections and it seems as though I still error out. Now stating No value given for one or more required parameters. It specifically indicates `rs.Open strSQL, ConnObj` when highlighting the error

Comment: When that happens, do `Debug.Print strSQL` and then copy the statement text from the Immediate window.  Create a new query in the query designer, switch to SQL View, paste in the text you copied, and try to run the query.  If Access thinks there is a parameter which needs a value, it will pop up an input box asking for a value, and that input dialog will include the "name" of whatever Access thinks is the parameter.  What is the name?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just a file path, the connection string should look more like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=O:\Department\Engineering\Einstein\00 - Systems Engineering\04 - Databases\VerificationLogDB.accdb;
```

More on the connection string here:

> https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

One other thing I see here is it's likely `O:` is a shared drive. It's worth mentioning that shared shared drives are **not** system (OS) -level constructs, but instead limited to a particular session, so the O: drive for one user may not be available for another, even on the same computer.

Answer (score -1):

Only create one connection and use it for all the queries

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestTransferDataToAccess2()

    Const db = "O:\Department\Engineering\Einstein\00 - Systems Engineering\04 - Databases\VerificationLogDB.accdb"
    Const WBPATH = "O:\Swap\Chicago\GenoF\Reading-2021-03-22-10-14-48.xls"
    
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim keyID As Long, keyName As String, hdr As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, ar, arHdrID
    Dim r As Long, n As Long, num As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    ' copy data from sheet to an array
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(WBPATH)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("As Found-CW Data")
    With ws
        ar = .Range("B16:C25")
        ReDim arHdrID(1 To UBound(ar))
    End With
    
     ' get keyid for keyname
    keyName = "Channel 1"
    keyID = GetKeyID(keyName, db)
    If keyID < 0 Then
        MsgBox "No KeyID for " & keyName, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' get header IDs
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = dbConnect(db)
        .CommandText = "SELECT HeaderID FROM tblHeaders WHERE HeaderName = ?"
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10)
    
        For r = 1 To UBound(ar)
            hdr = ar(r, 1)
            .Parameters(0) = hdr
            Set rs = .Execute
            If rs.EOF Then
                MsgBox "No HeaderID for " & hdr, vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If
            arHdrID(r) = rs.Fields(0)
            'Debug.Print r, arHdrID(r), rs.Fields(0)
        Next
        
        .ActiveConnection.Close
    End With
    
    ' prepare and execute insert command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = dbConnect(db)
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblTorqueData (headerID, keyID, torqueValue) VALUES (?,?,?)"
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p1", adBigInt, adParamInput)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p2", adBigInt, adParamInput)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p3", adNumeric, adParamInput)
    
        ' execute inserts
        For r = 1 To UBound(ar)
            .Parameters(0) = arHdrID(r) ' headerID
            .Parameters(1) = keyID
            .Parameters(2) = CDbl(ar(r, 2))
            .Execute num
            n = n + num
        Next
        
        .ActiveConnection.Close
    End With
    
    MsgBox n & " records inserted into " & db, vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
       
End Sub

Function GetKeyID(keyName, db) As Long
      
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    With New ADODB.Command
        .ActiveConnection = dbConnect(db)
        .CommandText = "SELECT KeyID FROM tblKeys WHERE KeyName = ?"
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, keyName)
        Set rs = .Execute
        If rs.EOF Then
            GetKeyID = -1
        Else
            GetKeyID = rs.Fields(0)
        End If
        .ActiveConnection.Close
    End With
    
End Function

Function dbConnect(db) As ADODB.Connection
   
    Set dbConnect = New ADODB.Connection
    With dbConnect
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = db
        .Open
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: No. Connections should be short-lived and not re-used, even in the old ADO. You can have one method to create and return a connection object that hides some of the boilerplate, though.